# babel and crossreftools incompatibility?

Tags: babel, babel-french, crossreftools

The following MWE is giving error:

```
./test.tex:10: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               :   
l.10 \section{A section}\label{sec:one`}
```

The source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:one}

Some math $1+1=2$.

\end{document}
```

There is *no* error if I:

- delete `\usepackage{crossreftools}`; OR
- omit `french` from the options to `babel; OR
- replace `french` by `german` or `russian`.

The Incompatibilities section of the docs for `crossreftools` say "...any unexpandable content written to the aux-file by redefinitions of `\label` or `@currentlabel` etc will cause problems.

Is that what the `french` option to `babel` is doing — writing such unexpandable content to the `.aux`?

If so, is there some work-around?

Comment: You can try the version currently in https://github.com/latex3/babel .

Comment: @JavierBezos: Is that newer than the stable version 3.34 that I just updated with the TeXLive Utility? If so, how do I use `latex` on the `.ins` so as NOT to replace the stable version already in my texmf tree? Don't I want to do that and just place the new files in the same folder as my source document, for testing?

Comment: @JavierBezos: the  problem arises not with `babel` itself, so far as I can see, but with `babel-french.ldf`, where `:` is made active. (Likewise `;` and `!` and `?`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

crossreftools creates a list of labels and tries to write the label key to it. That is a bit fragile ... You could add `\detokenize`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{crossreftools}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\crtaddlabeltotoc}[1]{%
  \ifcrtfinal
  \else
  \addcontentsline{\crt@listoflabelsfileextension}{\crt@listoflabelsstructurelevel}{%
   \protect\numberline{\expandafter\crtrefnumber\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}}#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\crtlistoflabels
\tableofcontents
\section{A section:abc }  \label{sec:onea} \label{seconea}
Some math $1+1=2$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: While that does fix the `crossreftools`+`babel-french` incompatibility for the `crossreftools` command `crtlistoflabels`that I raised, it does not fix the incompatibility with the other commands from that package, including its redefinition of the version of `\cref`(from `cleveref`).

Comment: There is another place where a `\detokenize` is needed, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The French option has made `:` active to produce French punctuation spacing and this interferes with its use in `\label` the simplest solution is simply to avoid punctuation characters in `\label`, `\label{sec-one}` works for example.

Normally `babel` ensures `:` still works in `\label` but apparently `crossreftools` disables that.

Comment: Ouch! In my actual book-length document, all the 1500+ labels include a colon. So I'm hoping there's some other workaround --  for `babel-french`.

Comment: @murray oh there is always a workaround:-) I don't actually know crossreftools package and I was hoping to avoid looking but I'll look tomorrow if no one else has answered.

Answer (score 1):

There is another place where a `\detokenize` is needed:

```
\renewcommand{\@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@@@crtextr@ct@ref\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\@@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax
  \crt@refundefined%
  \else
  \expandafter\expandafter\csname crt@ref@splitter@#2\endcsname\csname r@#1\endcsname%
  \fi
}
```

My preference is to make the changes in my own copy of `crossreftools.sty`. And then just replace the original definitions with the new ones. That means in each case the `\renewcommand` should be replaced by `\newcommand`.