# Another babel-french incompatibility with crossreftools

Tags: babel-french, crossreftools

With the indicated line commented-out, the following course using both `babel-french` and `crossreftools` gives the expected output from the two `crossreftools` commands near its end:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

%\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[theorem of Pythagoras]
  \label{thm:prelim}

  The square of the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares of the other two sides.

\end{theorem}

\crtrefanchor{thm:prelim} --- \verb!\crtrefanchor{thm:prelim}!

\crtrefname{thm:prelim} --- \verb!\crtrefanchor{thm:prelim}!

\end{document}
```

[image: new-babel-french-crossreftools-clash]

However, when that line is uncommented, this error occurs:

```
./clash.tex:23: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               :
l.23       \label{thm:prelim}
```

Undoubtedly the error has the same cause as noted in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510593/13492: the `french` option to `babel` makes `:` active, which interferes with the colon's use in the label.

A fix for another such class between `babel-french` and `crossreftools` was given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510641/13492.

**Question:** How can this incompatibility be fixed for these two `crossreftools` commands?

**Note: Why colons in labels?**

In the book-length document from which the preceding MWE arises, I've been using colons in labels because they nearly all already have hyphens embedded in the phrase following the colon, e.g.,`\label{thm:law-large-numbers}`. Such a label makes the type of theorem (or definition, etc.) visually separate from the terse description of that particular theorem (etc.).

I tried semicolon instead, but find that also no good, since `babel-french` makes it active, too.

Character `|` might do (hope it doesn't lead to other problems), but it's rather obtrusive compared with `:` in a label. (Still, it will take some work to replace the colons in some 1500-1600 labels without inadvertently replacing needed colons punctuation body text.)

Comment: You've been already advised not to use colons in labels.

Comment: @egreg: The problem is, it's too late, really: I have nearly 1600 labels in my book-length document, each and every one with a colon. I adopted that convention long before I found that I needed `crossreftools` to do some of the cross-referencing.

Comment: @egreg Good to know, I have used : in labels for years ;(. What#s your suggestion instead for structuring labels?

Comment: There is now an answer in another post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510641/113546

Answer (score 1):

This may help. I don't know if it is robust enough, but in simple cases it should work:

```
\edef\myoldcatcode{\the\catcode`\:}
\let\myoriglabel\label
\def\label{\catcode`\:=11 \mynewlabel}
\def\mynewlabel#1{\myoriglabel{#1}\catcode`\:=\myoldcatcode}
```

Comment: Seems not to be rubust: same error with `babel-french` and `crossreftools`, e.g., in something of the form `\MakeTextLowercase{\crtrefname{thm:main}}`.

Comment: Yes, because it mangles the catcode, it would only work at the outer level, not inside other macros.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since recent splits in the Oberdiek bundle, the etexcmds.sty package is no longer loaded automatically. It needs to be loaded explicitly for this MWE to compile properly, is this intended?

Comment: The additional fix to `crossreftools` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510641/13492 is needed, too.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make : safe when constructing csnames, something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
]{thmstyle}

\let\zzz\active@prefix
\def\active@prefix{\ifincsname\expandafter\string\else\expandafter\zzz\fi}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[theorem of Pythagoras]
  \label{thm:prelim}

  The square of the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares of the other two sides.

\end{theorem}

\crtrefanchor{thm:prelim} --- \verb!\crtrefanchor{thm:prelim}!

\crtrefname{thm:prelim} --- \verb!\crtrefanchor{thm:prelim}!

\end{document}
```

Comment: While that works, it does not work if one uses `\cref`, etc., from `cleveref`, whereas the method of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511212/13492 does work with `cleveref`.

Comment: @murray I know nothing:-) feel free to post a combined answer  and self accept. I am not sure Ive ever used cleverref so would take me a while to test any answer, better if you self answer I think.