# Which characters are safe to use in labels?

Tags: labels, active-characters

To my dismay, I've learned that it is unsafe to use the colon (`:`) in labels if you are using `babel-french` together with at least one other package, namely, `crossreftool`, which operates upon labels.

The reason is that `babel-french` makes `:` active (likewise `;` and `!` and `?`).

So I need a different character, instead of the colon, in labels, e.g.,in

```
\label{thm:law-large-numbers}
```

where the colon separates the type of object (theorem, definition, equation, etc.) being labeled from the hyphenated phrase identifying the particular object of that type.

(See [Another babel-french incompatibility with crossreftools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511030/another-babel-french-incompatibility-with-crossreftools) and [babel and crossreftools incompatibility?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510591/babel-and-crossreftools-incompatibility/510593#510593).)

**Question:**

Aside hyphen (`-`) and alphanumerics, which of these characters are safe to use in labels?

- period (`.`)
- bar character (`|`)
- at symbol (`@`)

That is, are there other packages that make either of these active and hence will cause trouble?

(For author's convenience both in typing source and in reading it, I really did like `:`, which visually separates just enough but is not as obtrusive as `|`. A single period is, of course, easy to type, but perhaps does not give sufficient visual separation.)

Comment: It is somewhat frequent that `|` gets set active for a short verb command, but that is usually done by the user or in some of the classes intended for documentation. So I'd say it is as safe as using `:`. The user should know if one can use it or not. But to my knowledge `.` should be pretty safe, I've yet to learn about a package which sets `.` active.

Comment: Assuming that `.` is safe, it might be safer to use `..` in case it turns not that `.` is not safe. That will make it significantly easier then to replace all instances of  `..` by another character (e.g., by `-`, which I want to avoid since I use in the "descriptive" part of the label.

Comment: Or you could use `@`, that one should be of category other in almost every LaTeX document (except someone forgot to put a `\makeatother` after a `\makeatletter`, but that would be definitely a user's fault).

Comment: And what about a simple space? e.g.; `\label{fig foo}` I can't imagine to someone thinking of using the space to do anything other than left a space. Moreover, as separator is unrivaled.

Comment: Note also the number of spaces is also irrelevant here, so you use different number of spaces in the labels and references without causing an error.