# crossreftools + docliccense gives error with restatement of restatable theorem

Tags: packages, theorems, thmtools, crossreftools

As the MWE below stands, after loading both `crossreftools` and `doclicense`, I get the following error on the *second* pdflatex pass when a `restatable` theorem is restated.

```
./restate-thm.tex:43: Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
```

I get **no** error when...

- `crossreftools` is loaded but `doclicense` is not; or
- `doclicense` is loaded but `crossreftools` is not; or
- `hyperref` is not loaded (but `crossreftools` and `doclicense` are loaded).

The same behavior occurs if I use the unstarred `restatable` instead of the starred `restatable*`.

What could cause the strange interaction?

I note that this only happened today. A couple of days ago, before some TeXLive 2020 updates, it did not occur! And I note that `thmtools` was updated 2020/07/16 (ver 69); whereas `doclicense` and other files it uses were not updated since 2020-06-28, and `crossreftools` was last updated 2019/01/03.

```
% file restate-thm.tex
\documentclass{book}

% Theorems...
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} % loads thm-restate
%
\swapnumbers
%
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter,style=plain]{theorem}
%
\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  notefont=\bfseries,notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
]{namedthmstyle}
%
\declaretheorem[style=namedthmstyle,name=Theorem,title = {},numberlike=theorem
]{namedtheorem}
\makeatother

% Links...
%\usepackage{hyperxmp} % to add metadata info into pdf
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% the problems??
\usepackage[type={CC},modifier={by-nc-nd},version={4.0},lang={english}]{doclicense}%
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Statement}

\begin{restatable*}[Theorem of Pythagoras]{namedtheorem}{PythagorasTheorem}
%\label{thm:Pythagoras}

The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares on the other two sides.

\end{restatable*}

\chapter{Proof}
Recall the theorem.
\PythagorasTheorem

\end{document}
```

When `thmtools` option `degug` is included, then after the *first* pdflatex pass I see the following in the log:

```
Chapter 2.
Key `Theorem of Pythagoras' with value `' ignored by label.
Key `Theorem of Pythagoras' with value `' ignored by name.
Key `Theorem of Pythagoras' with value `' ignored by continues.
Key `Theorem of Pythagoras' with value `' ignored by restate phase 1.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 44.
[3]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 44.
 (./restate-thm.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 44.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 44.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `restate-thm.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

...

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Comment: Hello, I am the current maintainer of `thmtools`. I can confirm this is not a regression issue caused by `thmtools` v69. Actually, the problem is reproducible with Overleaf's texlive 2019. Anyway, I will try to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

`crossreftools` v1.0 (2020-07-19) has fixed this issue, so the following patch is not necessary.

---

*Original answer:*

Try this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\crtaddlabeltotoc}[1]{%
  \ifcrtfinal
  \else
  % replace "\expandafter\crtrefnumber{#1}" with "\string\crtrefnumber{#1}"
  \addcontentsline{\crt@listoflabelsfileextension}{\crt@listoflabelsstructurelevel}{\protect\numberline{\string\crtrefnumber{#1}}#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This seems a bug of `crossreftools` and here is a minimum example reproduces the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabel{\protect\def\protect\x{x}}
\makeatother

text \label{key}
\end{document}
```

---

Some explanations:

- `corssreftools` has a `\crtlistoflabels` which outputs a list of labels stored in aux file `.lla`. For a label named `sec:xxx` of section 3 on page 5, its corresponding entry in list of labels would look like "3 sec:xxx ... ... 5". Here `3` is equivalent to the output of `\ref{sec:xxx}`.

  - Through first run of latex, `\crtaddlabeltotoc` is called to write necessary info to `.aux`. When `.aux` is input at the begin of document, `.lla` is created. And when `\crtlistoflabels` is used, `.lla` is input.
  - The whole `\crtlistoflabels` utility can be turned off by `crossreftools`'s package option `final.
- In the current implementation of `\crtaddlabeltotoc`, which extracts the reference value (plain output of `\ref{<label>}`) of a label,

  - firstly the `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\crtrefnumber{#1}` has no effect since the token after `\crtrefnumber` is `{`, unexpandable.
  - Secondly, this would write the result of fully expanded `\crtrefnumber{#1}` to `.aux`. `\crtrefnumber` *is* expandable, but the result of its expansion is not necessarily expandable.
- `thmtools`'s `restatable` environment *do* stores un-expandable staff in label's reference value, and this causes problems as long as it is used with `crossreftools`.

  - In OP's example, when `doclicense` is commented, there is still wrong contents in `.aux` file, for example (note the `\def \@arabic {\c@equation }` snippet)

  ```
  \@writefile{lla}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {\def \@arabic {\c@equation }{\@arabic {\c@equation }}\global \c@equation 0\relax }thmt@@PythagorasTheorem@data}{1}\protected@file@percent }
  ```

  - But, if user doesn't use `\crtlistoflabels`, the file `.lla` is never loaded. Hence the problem in contents of `.lla` is never uncovered.
  - In OP's example, when `doclicense` is uncommented, package `calc` is loaded. This makes the process of fully expansion of `\crtrefnumber{#1}` causing problems serious enough to raise an error.

Concerning the current fix, since the labels are already defined at the beginning of document, using `\crtrefnumber{<label name>}` rather than its expansion in `\crtlistoflabels` is safe. Therefore, `\string` replaces `\expandafter` to write `\crtrefnumber{#1}` to `.aux`.

After the fix,

```
\@writefile{lla}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {\crtrefnumber{thmt@@PythagorasTheorem@data}}thmt@@PythagorasTheorem@data}{1}\protected@file@percent }
```

is written to `.aux`.

Comment: @muzimuhi Z: Your fix resolves the immediate problem. But how do I reconcile it with a different redefinition of `\crtaddlabeltotoc` that fixes a conflict with `babel-french`, namely: `\renewcommand{\crtaddlabeltotoc}[1]{%
  \ifcrtfinal
  \else
  \addcontentsline{\crt@listoflabelsfileextension}{\crt@listoflabelsstructurelevel}{%
   \protect\numberline{\expandafter\crtrefnumber\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}}#1}%
  \fi
}` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510641/13492 ?

Comment: What does the bug you cite in `crossreftools` have to do with `doclicense`, though? I was getting the error only when `doclicense` was used, too (which seems weird).

Comment: @murray Because `doclicense` depends on `calc`, and it is `calc` that makes the problem serious enough to raise a bug when `.aux` is input at second run. When adding `\crtlistoflabels` to your example, you can get errors (though the error message varies) without `doclicense` and even without `hyperref`.

Comment: @murray I cannot reproduce your problem in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510591, either on my local texlive 2020 or on Overleaf's texlive 2019. It might be the fact that `babel-french.ldf` has fixed it.

Comment: @murray Using Overleaf's texlive 2018, the problem reproduces. It can be fixed by redefining `\crtaddlabeltotoc` by replacing `\expandafter\crtrefnumber{#1}` with `\string\crtrefnumber{\detokenize{#1}}`. This resolves problems reported both in referenced question and in current one.

Comment: And you can find the definition of `\crtaddlabeltotoc` in `crossreftools` v0.9 [here](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/crossreftools/crossreftools.sty?revision=49589&view=markup#l424).

Comment: @murray Hello, I've contacted the package author, and this issue has been fixed in `crossreftools` v1.0. Also see the beginning of my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for making that contact; the updated v1.0 crossreftools does fix the issue. (There are different issues with the package not yet fixed!)

Comment: @murray Would you please indicate links to or examples of those not yet fixed `crossreftools` issues?

Comment: The other place I know where `crossreftools` still needs fixing is indicated in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512175/13492.

Comment: @murray The problem is, with texlive 2020, I cannot reproduce the error you indicated in that question.